# Porting VB6 app to VB.Net: Can anyone ballpark how much effort this is?

Tags: vb.net, vb6, vb6-migration

In 2002 I did a pretty large VB6 app for a client. It used a lot of UserControls and a 3rd party menu control (for putting icons next to menu names). It had dynamically "splittable" panels, TreeViews with multi-state checkboxes, etc. A very rich UI. My total time on the project was about 500 hours, which the client graciously let me spread over *a whole month*. (Yeah, it was *that* kind of job.) They were very happy, though, and they paid the bill on time with no argument.

So after having no contact with them for years, they suddenly call and wonder if I can update the app to .Net for them. My initial reaction is just to decline, since I don't use VB.Net. And having read a bunch of posts on SO about the difficulties of porting, etc., etc., I'm even *more* inclined to decline, so to speak.

Still, before I tell them no I am interested in roughly quantifying the effort it would take. I would love to hear from anyone who has done this kind of thing and has a feel for how much work it is. Was it:

- Significantly less than the effort you used on the original?
- Somewhat less than the effort you used on the original?
- The same as the effort you used on the original?
- More?
- A lot more?

Please only respond if you have actually done this kind of port. And the answer doesn't have to be exact, since I really am only trying to ballpark this. My feeling is that the effort will be at least as much as it took for the original, if not more. But I could be wrong. Thanks for any help.

Comment: Do you use C#.net? This will be a factor in how difficult it is for you to work with VB.Net.

Comment: @Brian: I have used C# since about 2005, but it's not my bread and butter these days.

Comment: in my answer, I supposed that you didn´t know .net platform. If you have used C#, the disadvantage that I described minimizes...

Another question, I´m pretty sure, but just in case: If the previous application is a desktop application, we are now talking about another desktop application in .NET, aren´t we?

Comment: I'd consider just porting to C#.net instead of VB.net if the client will allow it.  From an "I'm a manager and don't know coding" perspective, this is superior (more people use it), so it may not be a proposal that bothers your client.  Unless they already have VB.net developers and want them to mess with your source, I can't think of much benefit in using VB.net instead of C#.

Comment: Their only requirement is that an application written in programming language X must be "updated" (rewritten) into programming langauge Y with the same functionality? That smells.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I have done what you've been asked. In my case it was an (amateur) bowling tournament mgmt system: Member database mgmt (personal info, IRS/Winnings info, mailing lists etc etc etc) , tournament mgmt (player assignments, scoring, lane ticket generation, check register for winnings and side-pots, etc etc etc) as well as IRS EDI generation for all winners in a given year. Plus about a billion little items scattered across ~ 50 screens/sub-screens.

The key is CLIENT UNDERSTANDING -- You must be clear that they understand that this is not trivial; this is a new adventure for BOTH of you (particularly if you are a new-comer to VB.Net) If they liked your work before then they may very well give you the leeway/freedom to learn VB.Net on their nickel.

Reading some of the previous answers let me make a few suggestions (based upon 30 years experience as a software developer, the last 20 of which as a consultant....)

1. TAKE THEIR MONEY IF THEY OFFER IT. You need to bring your skillset into the 20th century; let them pay for it (again, if they agree.) They *may be* Magazine surfing and want "the latest stuff" for NO GOOD REASON -- but maybe they realize that they can extend the life of (your) application by this port. In essence they may have all kinds of goofy reasons for doing it... if they are NOT hiring you to DECIDE whether or not this port is a good idea. Then you may express any dismay you have about the decision PROCESS out of good client relationship building; BUT if they want to do this then it might as well be your job.
2. Take all this mumbo-jumbo re: C# vs VB.Net with a grain of salt. I have worked EXCLUSIVELY in VB.Net / ASPX.net (vs C#) since its inception and have yet to come across ANY functionality NOT attainable in VB.Net. There are some 'purists' out there that just view VB.Net as a toy. Well, I came from the days of writing in Assembler, then C, then C++ (And you can throw in Fortran, PL1 for good measure) then VB5, then 6, then VB.Net ... and NOW JAVA for Android. Its ALL GOOD FUN... and each has it merits and drawbacks. Remember that C# and VB.Net are essentially just GUIs to achieve a meta-language intermediate. You can write a TERRIBLE (as measured by efficiency or memory use or whatever metric you choose!) Program in C# and a great one in VB.Net (and vice-versa.) DO NOT EQUATE GOOD PROGRAMMING WITH LANGUAGE SYNTAX. (... C# is "superior" ????  Gimme a break.)
3. I chose to allow the Visual Studio do most of the heavy lifting for the first pass. Then you go through the gazzillion errors and clean it up. It goes pretty fast.
4. BUT you need to decide whether or not to take advantage of any framework benefits that you had hand-coded in VB6. E.G. looping through a string to locate a specific character(s) is now as simple as The_String.IndexOf("c") I found that in my case I went through the code several times and took better and better advantage of the Class (i.e. object orientation) as well as framework goodies as I became comfortable... this adds to your development time (see CLIENT UNDERSTANDING mantra) BUT your code WILL BE MORE Efficient then it ever could have been in VB6. You *could* simply port to get the errors out and not take ANY advantage necessarily from the framework.
5. I have not found any issue with 3rd party active-x controls. You can add a reference to FRAMEWORK objects, COM objects, etc. It may even be likely that the control vendor has a .Net (managed code) version... OR there may be suitable alternatives since you wrote the thing in VB6. (See CLIENT UNDERSTANDING mantra)

So if your *still* reading, then now I will finally tell you that the second attempt at my application in VB.Net CONVERTED/PORTED from VB6 was ~ 1/3 of the original time to get to a working model... and I was learning the framework as well. (If your confident in your skill set, have learned a few languages through the years you will get the gist of VB.Net quickly --- its the SUBTLETIES that take awhile.)

I must caution you that the thing that can REALLY kill you if you do not preach the CLIENT UNDERSTANDING well enough is if they want to make changes WHILE you're porting (and this is VERY LIKELY since they've been using it for awhile... I was very true in my case as well.

There is no hard and fast rule here. It could be that changes will actually HELP YOU get to a better understanding the framework faster OR changes could be a real pain. Only you can determine which flavor they might be. AND if they look to be the PAINFUL type -- you might ask to do the conversion first so that you have reliably reproduced the functionality -- THEN go back and review the code to make changes and take advantage of the framework as necessary. But, as I said, there is NO Hard and Fast rules here -- and don't let the purists tell you differently --- remember they are probably the same guys that said that PASCAL was going to take over the world!

Comment: So refreshing to hear from someone that hasn't fallen for the now almost fundamentalist view that insists that C# is 'superior' to VB.NET.  +1 just for that.  I learned C# first, then switched to VB when I discovered how much better the auto-complete and intellisense still are.

Comment: Thanks, Tobrien. All the answers here were helpful, but yours was comprehensive and exhausting, and so I award you the checkmark. I appreciate you taking the time to write all this. You've answered a lot of the nagging little questions that have been troubling me about this.Thanks much!

Comment: Robusto -- 'exhausting' --- oh, I really hope you  meant 'exhaustive' ;<>)  VB.Net is a GREAT Tool for development (any kind not just PROTOTYPE) GOOD LUCK !

Comment: +1. Nice answer. Although there are some ActiveX controls that are not compatible with .Net (e.g. any container control). See chapter 13 in the free book http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vbrun/ms788236.aspx

Comment: @MarkJ Agreed. I'd always look (goo-goo-google) around for updated versions or .Net replacements for older VB6 style controls.

Comment: @Tobrien: Yes, I was thinking "exhaustive" but my fingers typed "exhausting." What's exhausting is working on Saturday, as I was doing, and all work and no play makes my fingres pla ytric kson me.

Answer (score 4):

> So after having no contact with them for years, they suddenly call and wonder if I can update the app to .Net for them.

You need to ask **why** they want this done.

It's a Bad Plan(tm) for clients to be making technical decisions on a whim. Before applying any solution, thoroughly understand their needs and their problem. Only after you understand the problem as they do should you make recommendations.

It could be that they're infatuated with a buzzword and want to be using the latest thing, or it could be any of a million other things. The solution to their problem could be something really easy, but if you don't find out what their problem is, you will never know the best way to solve that problem.

Comment: Why they want this done? If it is like our company, because our customers discovered that it doesn't run on Vista.

Answer (score 3):

**I would plan on it taking about 50% of the time and effort it took to create it in the first place.**

I have done EXACTLY what you are asking about for a commercial software product that consisted of roughly 500 kloc.  We balanced the desire for refactoring with the desire to get something working and released as quickly as possible.

It took nearly the entire team about 1 full year to get it done...for a product that took 4 years to create in the first place.  It was a gigantic undertaking..not to be underestimated.

Answer (score 2):

We are doing that exact thing right now, however it's slightly different.  Instead of one huge application, there are many smaller ones.  However, there are a few bigger ones in the list.  What we found out is that it was significantly less work than we originally thought. BUT...the biggest unknowns had to do with third-party controls we had.  If you have a lot of those to basically redesign, you will probably be looking at more work.

The one good suggestion I have is to use Visual Studio 2008 for the conversion (not VS 2005).  There were far less problems when using the built-in converter in VS 2008 than there was with VS 2005.  Not sure why, it just was that way.

So, I can't say that you won't spend 500 hours again, but most likely not.  Most of your time should be spent on testing to verify no functionality was lost.

Answer (score 2):

In my opinion,

Visual Basic 6 and Visual Basic .NET are so different that you should forget about their coincidence in their name, and treat this as a migration to .NET =P

I think that you have one big advantage and one disadvantage:

- **Advantage:** you allready know what the application has to do. Probably you´ll have some meetings with your clients, in order to add some modifications or new features, but you have the major part of the requirements very clear. You´ll even have the old working application to see while you, or your team, are coding.
- **Disadvantage**: you´ll have to learn a new language. Saying how much time is going to take, is very subjective. I´ve allways thought that learning a new language is not the problem, the big problem would be if you have to learn to program!. But you do know to program. You´ll know what you want to do, and you´ll have only to search how to do it in the new languaje.

Since you have to learn .NET, If you have to estimate, I think that you should suppose that it will take you **at least the same as the previous application**, even more.

My advice is too take the chance to learn this new language. And if you are more inclined to decline the project, let me give you another idea... Maybe you could estimate a little module of your application, and tell the client that you´ll try to do that module, to see how much it takes to you. The client should pay this little module, even if you decide not to continue.

You can´t tell the client that you know all the requirements, so they are saving money with you, in some way. And that they should take this little risk (we are talking about a little module), because who better than you to make the project, you know the old application perfectly!

If the client is right with this, you´ll can take the decision with more arguments. And If finally you decide to continue, with this little module done, you can estimate the whole project better than before.

*Sorry, my English isn´t very good, and probably I´ve made many gramatical errors.*

**EDIT** grammar mistakes... =P

Answer (score 1):

I'd go for two months this time.

But seriously, that's probably not far off — or even low — because the client will have some *reason* for needing the port done.  It won't be just a straight port - they'll want some "small little enhancement" that will blow the whole project up.

Additionally, I'd worry a bit about the third party controls.  Most of the rest of it should convert okay, but there's sometimes an issue finding a good analog to a 3rd party control in .Net.

I'm also concerned that you don't use vb.net.  If you're a c# user and wanted to re-implement that way you'd be fine, but otherwise this is a non-starter.  VB.Net is just different enough from vb6 for you to get yourself into trouble.

Aside from all that, I would expect it to be less work this time than last, because you have a very explicit design laid out in front of you that you merely need to follow.

Answer (score 1):

This is a huge topic.

You should take a look at MS' Free Book - [Upgrading Microsoft Visual Basic 6.0 to Microsoft Visual Basic .NET](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vbrun/ms788236.aspx).

Were you to rewrite from scratch, rather than simply try and port the previous application, it shouldn't take too long. VB.Net has some features that will make the new application build take shorter. As it seems that you don't know VB.Net already, what will take you the most time is learn how to do things *the new way<sub>(tm)</sub>*.